# tp-link 1043nd no internet after flashing to gargoyle firmware

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, openwrt

all!!

ive recently bought a tp-link wr1043nd version 1.10 and flashed gargoyle firmware 1.5.9 onto it (after intermediate step of flashing from stock firmware to german version of firmware)

ive read that the intermediate step of flashing to the german firmware should preserve the WAN port (prevent the WAN port from being disabled, if other alternative firmwares were installed to the router)...

right now, the gargoyle firmware has been successfully flashed, but no internet!! (i believe that the lack of internet is similar to the WAN port being disabled--issue that i was trying to prevent)

any input as to how to revert back to stock firmware? (trying very hard to avoid a 'brick') a link to the appropriate, correct firmware would be appreciated.. as well as step by step instruction would be extremely helpful!!

not very good with technoogy in general, but looking to use some features in third party firmware to... a) control bandwidth quota per device b) monitor bandwidth usage as well...

I am also up for suggestions as to new router choices that would be compatible with any of the third party firmwares that offer the 'bandwidth quota control' feature... as well as any routers that come with the 'bandwidth quota' feature already straight out of the box!

thanks all!!

patiently awaiting all expertise!!